# How to use mysql client (sql-mysql-program) from a docker container?

Tags: sql-mode, docker

I am running MySQL inside a docker container. When I try to connect to it  using `M-x sql-mysql` I see the following error:

> Unable to locate SQL program ‘mysql’

Yeah, I don't have mysql-client installed and would like to use it from a docker container. So I changed `sql-mysql-program` to be `/usr/local/bin/docker exec -it fb34d517502c mysql`, but again received an error:

> Unable to locate SQL program ‘/usr/local/bin/docker exec -it fb34d517502c mysql’

Is there a way to use mysql-client from the docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using an awesome [docker-tramp.el](https://github.com/emacs-pe/docker-tramp.el). It offers TRAMP method `docker` to access running containers, so I can do:

```
C-x C-f /docker:container:/path/to/file
```

And then use `sql-mode` as usual